# Docker + reverse-proxy(nginx) + subdirectory as root + wordpress(apache) + multisite

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, multisite

Note: Translate from portuguese to english on google translate, sorry...

I'm trying to put a wordpress website online being that the root of wordpress is already in a subdirectory (eg: `webplace.example.br/subdirectory/` <--root-wordpress), but every time I set up the multisite and try using them, it starts to give problems. I'm using a container with [nginx:alpine](https://store.docker.com/images/nginx) as a reverse proxy, for another container [wordpress:php7.2](https://store.docker.com/images/wordpress) on the same host, I'm using this setting in nginx:

Note2: not wordpress I'm just trying to put a base online, I'm not going to create/edit the site.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name webplace.example.br;

    location /subdirectory/ {
        proxy_pass  http://container_wordpress:80/subdirectory/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

, after getting so much I ended up creating an alias in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in the wordpress container, like this:

```
...
Alias /subdirectory /var/www/html
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
...
```

After installing normally, I already activate the multisite by following these steps:

1st, added the line below, above `/* That's all...` in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

2st, soon after I updated the page, it was in tools> install network, it gave the 'ok', it adds this text just below the line previously entered in the same file:

```
define ('MULTISITE', true);
define ('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define ('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'webplace.example.br');
define ('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/subdirectory/');
define ('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define ('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

3st, and this part in `.htaccess`, commenting on everything else:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) var/www/html/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ var/www/html/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

With this the site continues to work normal, but when I create another site, I put some things in it and I try to access it, the site is all broken without style, pure text only, and it gets worse when I try to access wp-admin from multisite it does not even open and says that it redirected too much, to get an idea the url looks like `webplace.example.br/subdirectory/<multisite>/wp-admin`.

**Can anyone see a light at the end of the tunnel or do you think it will never work?**

Note3: I have tried several tutorials, but they never cover all the things I use (reverse proxy (nginx), subdirectory, multisite, container, wordpress (apache)), making them not work.

Note4: There are chances that I have not understood or implemented the tutorial solutions right.

Note5: Another type of implementation I am also accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a subdomain for your wordpress instance e.g. `blog.example.com`.

Set the subdomain up on your NGINX reverse proxy to point to your wordpress container

Install WordPress via the `blog.example.com` subdomain

Update your reverse proxy so `/blog` also points to your wordpress container

Your wordpress will be accessible via `blog.example.com` and `example.com/blog`.

When you visit `example.com/blog` all your wp-includes/wp-content will be loaded via the `blog.example.com` site while WordPress will continue to let you visitors click around remaining on the `example.com/blog` site